# How prove this $ \sum_{i\neq j}|x_{i}-y_{i}|\ge\sum|x_{i}-x_{j}|+\sum|y_{i}-y_{j}|$

Tags: inequality

let $x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{n},y_{1},y_{2},\cdots,y_{n}\in \mathbb{C}$,
show that
$$
\sum_{i\neq j,i=1,j=1}^{n}|x_{i}-y_{j}|\ge\sum_{i=1,j=1}^{n}|x_{i}-x_{j}|+\sum_{i=1,j=1}^{n}|y_{i}-y_{j}|$$

Comment: Is $j$ fixed or do you sum over $i$ and $j$?

Comment: I have edit,Thank you

Comment: The expression on the LHS should be $|x_i-y_j|$, right? Otherwise, the inequality is not true.

Comment: oh,I'm sorry, I have edit

Comment: Even then it is false. Just choose $x_i = y_i$ and you will get $0 \geq \sum{|x_i-x_j|}$, which is false except for $x_1 = … = x_n$.

Comment: The title should have $y_j$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n=2$ and choose $x_1=y_2=0$ and $x_2=y_1=1$. Then the left side is $0$ since the two possible nonzero contributions $|x_1-y_1|$ and $|x_2-y_2|$ are ruled out by the summation restriction $i \ne j.$ But the right side is positive, since it contains at least the term $|x_1-x_2|=1.$

I believe the inequality might hold if the $\ge$ is replaced by $\le$, by use of, for $i \ne j$

$$|x_i-y_j|-|x_i-y_i| \le |y_i-y_j|, \\ 
|x_i-y_j|-|x_j-y_j| \le |x_i-x_j|,$$
each of these obtained by a rearranged triangle inequality. The extra subtracted terms on the left are of the type excluded in the left sum of the proposed inequality of the OP (with the inequality sense reversed). Looking at some small $n$ however, I couldn't get an actual proof using the $\le$ direction either.

Added: The inequality doesn't hold in the $\le$ version either, since one can take all the $x_i$ equal to $a$ and all the $y_i$ equal to $b$, which makes the right side $0$ but each term on the left side is $|a-b|$.

Comment: oh,Thank you,it's $\le $

Comment: @math110 See added comment to answer, the $\le$ version doesn't work either.